# Cosmos DB REST API with Emulator (for the moment)

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to use the Cosmos DB RestAPI to list the databases on my local (emulator) instance and not getting very far. Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong here...

```
var crypto = require("crypto");  
var request = require('request');

function getAuthorizationTokenUsingMasterKey(verb, resourceType, resourceId, date, masterKey) {  
    var key = new Buffer(masterKey, "base64");  

    var text = (verb || "").toLowerCase() + "\n" +   
           (resourceType || "").toLowerCase() + "\n" +   
           (resourceId || "") + "\n" +   
           date.toLowerCase() + "\n" +   
           "" + "\n";  

    var body = new Buffer(text, "utf8");  
    var signature = crypto.createHmac("sha256", key).update(body).digest("base64");  

    var MasterToken = "master";  

    var TokenVersion = "1.0";  

    return encodeURIComponent("type=" + MasterToken + "&ver=" + TokenVersion + "&sig=" + signature);  
}  

function doTest() {

  const key = getAuthorizationTokenUsingMasterKey("get","dbs","", "Fri, 5 Jan 2018 04:31:00 GMT", "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==")
  console.log(key);

  var headers = {}
  headers['content-length'] = body.length;
  headers['authorization'] = key
  headers["x-ms-version"] = "2017-02-22"
  headers["x-ms-date"] = "2018-01-05T04:31:00Z"

  request({method : "get", "url": "https://localhost:8081/dbs", "headers": headers, "body": body}, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log("Error is : " + JSON.stringify(error));
    console.log("Response is " + JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
    console.log("body is " + JSON.stringify(body))
  });
}
doTest();
```

When I run this against the Cosmos DB Emulator I get the following output..

```
G:\Node-8\NodeExample\node_modules\oracle-movie-ticket-demo>node cosmosTest
```

type%3Dmaster%26ver%3D1.0%26sig%3DKvaXXxoeUpN6QuKz%2BA1w91EWHSdo0RdBjtI46tDBrgY%3D

```
Error is : null
Response is {
  "statusCode": 401,
  "body": "{\"code\":\"Unauthorized\",\"message\":\"The input authorization token can't serve the request. Please check that the expected payload is built as per the protocol, and check the key being used. Server used the following payload to sign: 'get\\ndbs\\n\\n2018-01-05t04:31:00z\\n\\n'\\r\\nActivityId: 0a00a781-f393-41e5-8ac0-4526af9110cc, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/1.19.102.5\"}",
  "headers": {
    "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "content-location": "https://localhost:8081/dbs",
    "server": "Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0",
    "x-ms-activity-id": "0a00a781-f393-41e5-8ac0-4526af9110cc",
    "x-ms-gatewayversion": "version=1.19.102.5",
    "date": "Fri, 05 Jan 2018 04:31:37 GMT",
    "connection": "close"
  },
  "request": {
    "uri": {
      "protocol": "https:",
      "slashes": true,
      "auth": null,
      "host": "localhost:8081",
      "port": "8081",
      "hostname": "localhost",
      "hash": null,
      "search": null,
      "query": null,
      "pathname": "/dbs",
      "path": "/dbs",
      "href": "https://localhost:8081/dbs"
    },
    "method": "get",
    "headers": {
      "content-length": 0,
      "authorization": "type%3Dmaster%26ver%3D1.0%26sig%3DKvaXXxoeUpN6QuKz%2BA1w91EWHSdo0RdBjtI46tDBrgY%3D",
      "x-ms-version": "2017-02-22",
      "x-ms-date": "2018-01-05T04:31:00Z"
    }
  }
}
body is "{\"code\":\"Unauthorized\",\"message\":\"The input authorization token can't serve the request. Please check that the expected payload is built as per the protocol, and check the key being used. Server used the following payload to sign: 'get\\ndbs\\n\\n2018-01-05t04:31:00z\\n\\n'\\r\\nActivityId: 0a00a781-f393-41e5-8ac0-4526af9110cc, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/1.19.102.5\"}"
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite familiar with Node.js code so I tried to access Azure Cosmos Emulator via REST API with the java code as below .It works well for me.

```
import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.Base64;

import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class ListDataBaseRest {
    private static final String key = "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==";

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        String urlString = "https://localhost:8081/dbs";
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(urlString)).openConnection();
        getFileRequest(connection, key);
        connection.connect();


        System.out.println("Response message : " + connection.getResponseMessage());
        System.out.println("Response code : " + connection.getResponseCode());

        BufferedReader br = null;
        if (connection.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((connection.getErrorStream())));
        } else {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((connection.getInputStream())));
        }
        System.out.println("Response body : " + br.readLine());
    }

    public static void getFileRequest(HttpURLConnection request, String key)
            throws Exception {
        SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        fmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        String date = fmt.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()) + " GMT";
        String stringToSign = "GET".toLowerCase() + "\n"
                + "dbs".toLowerCase() + "\n"
                + "" + "\n"
                + date.toLowerCase() + "\n"
                + "" + "\n";
        System.out.println("stringToSign : " + stringToSign);
        String auth = getAuthenticationString(stringToSign);

        request.setRequestMethod("GET");
        request.setRequestProperty("x-ms-date", date);
        request.setRequestProperty("x-ms-version", "2017-02-22");
        request.setRequestProperty("Authorization", auth);
        request.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/query+json");

    }

    private static String getAuthenticationString(String stringToSign) throws Exception {
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(Base64.decode(key), "HmacSHA256"));
        String authKey = new String(Base64.encode(mac.doFinal(stringToSign.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
        System.out.println("authkey:" + authKey);
        String auth = "type=master&ver=1.0&sig=" + authKey;
        auth = URLEncoder.encode(auth);
        System.out.println("authString:" + auth);
        return auth;
    }

}
```

***Output Result:***

[image]

> Error code 401
>
> The input authorization token can't serve the request.
>   Please check that the expected payload is built as per the protocol,
>   and check the key being used.

Per my experience , above error is relate to `Authorization header` generation. I tried to find the difference between out codes. I notice that your **`date`** parameter is static , not getting the current time.

In addition , the `x-ms-date` header 's format does not conform to standard. It need to be like `Tue, 01 Nov 1994 08:12:31 GMT`.

Any concern , please let me know.

Comment: If your default locale is not English then you need to set ENGLISH local in SimpleDateFormat

Answer (score 1):

Masterkey signature generation should use RFC 7231 format. Here is the
[signature specification reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/access-control-on-documentdb-resources#constructkeytoken).

For node, below code reference might be of help

[Signature generation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-node/blob/8a5f353cab484271ecd2cc6c6b22c0481eeec8f7/source/lib/auth.js)

[Usage](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-node/blob/8a5f353cab484271ecd2cc6c6b22c0481eeec8f7/source/lib/base.js#L267-L273)